# Checking the formula of the square of a sum

Tags: summation

The square of a sum reads

$$\left(\sum_ia_i\right)^2=\sum_ia^2_i+2\sum_{i<j}a_ia_j$$.

In Mathematica code for i=1 to 5 we get:

```
T = Expand[(Sum[a[i], {i, 5}])^2]
a[1]^2 + 2 a[1] a[2] + a[2]^2 + 2 a[1] a[3] + 2 a[2] a[3] + a[3]^2 + 2 a[1] a[4] + 2 a[2] a[4] + 2 a[3] a[4] + a[4]^2 + 2 a[1] a[5] +  2 a[2] a[5] + 2 a[3] a[5] + 2 a[4] a[5] + a[5]^2

P = Expand[Sum[a[i]^2, {i, 5}] + 2 Sum[a[i]*a[j], {i, 4}, {j, 5}]]
3 a[1]^2 + 4 a[1] a[2] + 3 a[2]^2 + 4 a[1] a[3] + 4 a[2] a[3] + 
 3 a[3]^2 + 4 a[1] a[4] + 4 a[2] a[4] + 4 a[3] a[4] + 3 a[4]^2 + 
 2 a[1] a[5] + 2 a[2] a[5] + 2 a[3] a[5] + 2 a[4] a[5] + a[5]^2
```

$T-P$ should be zero, but:

```
T - P
2 a[1]^2 - 2 a[1] a[2] - 2 a[2]^2 - 2 a[1] a[3] - 2 a[2] a[3] - 
 2 a[3]^2 - 2 a[1] a[4] - 2 a[2] a[4] - 2 a[3] a[4] - 2 a[4]^2
```

What is the proble here?

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of this with other powers, you should look at `PowerSymmetricPolynomial`, `AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial`, and `MomentConvert`.  Here's an example that matches your question:  `MomentConvert[PowerSymmetricPolynomial[1]^2, "AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial"] // TraditionalForm` which results in $A_{\{1,1\}}+A_{\{2\}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
P = Expand[Sum[a[i]^2, {i, 1, 5}] + 2 Sum[a[i]*a[j], {j, 5}, {i, j - 1}]]
```

Comment: This works but would it be safer to use `{j, 2, 5}, {i, j - 1}` rather than `{j, 5}, {i, j - 1}`?  I ask because I don't know the answer.  `a[0]` is legitimate and I don't understand why `a[0]` isn't created using `{j, 5}, {i, j - 1}`.

Comment: @JimB Table Iterators `{k,m}`run from k=1 to k=m, so for j=1 the second iterator would be forced to start with i=0, but is 'considered' out of range and is omitted. See Help 'Table'